# How can I set values for certain keys within multidimensional arrays to null?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to unset an array value but not the key

Before:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45
            [type] => 1
            [lgsize] => 10
            [lgid] => 9
            [rank] => 4
            [winprize] => 3000
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [type] => 1
            [lgsize] => 10
            [lgid] => 9
            [rank] => 4
            [winprize] => 2000
        )
)
```

After:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45
            [type] => 1
            [lgsize] => 10
            [lgid] => 9
            [rank] => 4
            [winprize] => 
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46
            [type] => 1
            [lgsize] => 10
            [lgid] => 9
            [rank] => 4
            [winprize] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: `$array[1]['winprize'] = ""`

Comment: execute these two commands : 
unset($array[0][winprize]);
unset($array[1][winprize]);

Comment: unset($array[0][winprize]); unset($array[1][winprize]); doesn't work. it removes the key.

Comment: @B.Desai so easy.

Comment: Do you want to set the value to `null` or an empty string? Since you use the work *unset* it suggests the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your ***array length*** can be ***increased***

Do it like below:-

```
foreach($array as &$arr){ // iterate over array
   $arr['winprize'] = ''; // empty value of desired key
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/847434

Comment: When you iterate by reference it is better to unset value variable after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using sizeof function

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
  $array[$i]['winprize'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Two things: a) how about using `count()` instead of the alias function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php), and b), the array might not be 0-indexed, and the keys might not be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

In looping please leave it blank.

e.g.

```
$array[0]['winprize'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use `array_map()`:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 45,
        'type' => 1,
        'lgsize' => 10,
        'lgid' => 9,
        'rank' => 4,
        'winprize' => 3000,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 46,
        'type' => 1,
        'lgsize' => 10,
        'lgid' => 9,
        'rank' => 4,
        'winprize' => 2000,
    ),
);

$cleaned = array_map(function (array $element) {
    // only set null as value if the key actually exists
    if (array_key_exists('winprize', $element)) {
        $element['winprize'] = null;
    }

    return $element;
}, $data);

var_dump($cleaned);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/EskKq